# Passing code as parameter C#

Tags: c#, function, parameters

I'm trying to pass a reference to a function as a parameter

It's hard to explain

I'll write some example pseudo code

```
(calling function)

function(hello());

function(pass)
{
   if this = 0 then pass
   else
}

hello()
{
   do something here
}
```

Sorry if it does not make much sense

But I'm trying to reduce used code and I thought this would be a good idea.

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: i am unable to achieve this is C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass code to a method by using [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx), for example, the [Action delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx):

```
void MyFunction(Action action)
{
    if (something == 0)
    {
        action();
    }
}

void Hello()
{
    // do something here
}
```

*Usage:*

```
MyFunction(Hello);
```

Comment: Thank you dtb! thats exacally what i was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

> I'm trying to pass a reference to a function as a parameter
>
> It's hard to explain

It may be hard to explain, but it is very easy to implement: the code below calls `MyFunction` passing it a parameterized piece of code as a parameter.

```
static void MyFunction(Action<string> doSomething) {
    doSomething("world");
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    MyFunction((name) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}!", name);
    });
}
```

You can use delegate types provided by the system (`Action` and `Func`) or [write your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
using System;

public class Example
{

    public void Method1(Action hello)
    {
        // Call passed action.
        hello();
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        // Do something here
    }

    public void Method3()
    {
        Method1(Method2);
    }
}
```